# How to pass Javascript variable (JSON Data) in angular for loading dynamic data in the table

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-datatables

How to pass Javascript variable in angular, this.http.get(jsvariable) for loading dynamic data in the table

```
public jsondata = [
      { id: 860, firstName: "Superman", lastName: "Yoda" },
      { id: 861, firstName: "xyz", lastName: "Abc" }
    ];
```

Need to call js variable

```
 this.http.get(this.jsondata)
    .subscribe(res => {
      this.results3 = res as any;
    });
```

[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-datatables-gitter-dhlsa7?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to do a http call because the json is inside of you code, I mean you have the reference of thisobject to used directly

only wrap the jeson into a function, and call this function whenever you want

```
getJsonData(){
 return [
      { id: 860, firstName: "Superman", lastName: "Yoda" },
      { id: 861, firstName: "xyz", lastName: "Abc" }
    ];
}
// OR The same function simulating you are getting an observable
// you need to import 'of' from rxjs
getJsonData(){
 return of([
      { id: 860, firstName: "Superman", lastName: "Yoda" },
      { id: 861, firstName: "xyz", lastName: "Abc" }
    ]);
}
```

*The **http** call its used when you are going to do a http request to some server or some API provider.*